# Empty WPF DataGrid should be filled by user

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using DataGrid view in WPF which is inserted by the following XAML Code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid" IsManipulationEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Now I add a column in my C# Code

```
DataGridTextColumn c0 = new DataGridTextColumn();
c0.Header = "Test";
c0.Binding = new Binding("TimeToRamp");
c0.Width = 110;
DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid.Columns.Add(c0);
```

and a line

```
DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid.Items.Add(new DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid_Single_Pump_Item() { TimeToRamp = 0.0});
```

where

```
public class DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid_Single_Pump_Item
{
   public double TimeToRamp { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine and results in one cell with value 0. Now the user should be able to change this value. How ever Selecting the cell and pressing any key results in crashing of the programm.

> Exception Type System.InvalidOperationException, Additional Information EditItem is not allowed.

Any idea of howto to allow the user to do this?

Comment: Try changing `IsManipulationEnabled="True"`  into `IsReadOnly="False"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid, instead of inserting items to the `Items` property:

```
var list = new ObservableCollection<DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid_Single_Pump_Item>();
list.Add(new DVA_Zyklus_DataGrid_Single_Pump_Item() { TimeToRamp = 0.0 });
dg.ItemsSource = list;
```

I think its better to follow MVVM approach to fill the DataGrid. There are lots of posts regarding it, such as [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid).